# DataTables Resizing columns not working properly with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I want to develop a table with the ability to resize columns by clicking and dragging (I have done this using ColReorderWithResize plugin).

However, when I use scroll option and I try to resize the header column, the table is not getting aligned with the header when the header is resized.

Here is a [fiddle script](http://jsfiddle.net/heavensteel/KqH7L/1/).

What I would like is that if I resize header column (e.g. Browser column) then the body column should align with header column. Is this normal behaviour in ColReorderWithResize when I want to use a scrollbar?

Note I am using:

DataTables 1.9.4

ColReorderWithResize 1.0.7

```
var $table = $("#demo table");
$table.dataTable({
  "sDom": "Rlfrtip",
  "sScrollY":($(window).height() - 300) + "px",

  "fnDrawCallback": function() {
    $(window).unbind('resize').bind('resize', function () {
      that.applyTableHeight();
    });
  },
  applyTableHeight:function () {
    var sScrollY = ($(window).height() - this.staticHeight) + "px";
    $(".dataTables_scrollBody").css("height", sScrollY);
    this.calculateTableWidth();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this .. redraw the datatable it will effect.

$("#table_id").dataTable().fnDraw();

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tblname").dataTable({
        autoWidth: false,
        oLanguage: {"sZeroRecords": ' ', "sEmptyTable": ' ' },
        select: true,
        scrollY:        500,
        scrollX:        false,
        deferRender:    true,
        scroller:       false,
        paging:   false,
        ordering: false,
        info:     false
    });
 $(window).resize(function() {
        $("#tblname").dataTable().fnDraw();
                 });
```

This resolved my problem if you use datatables and scroll plugin.